# After urinating and making wadu a thin line of urine appears; do I need to redo wadu?

Tags: wudu, taharah

After urination and performing wadu, sometimes a thin line of urine arises but it's not enough to form a drop of urine. After cleaning it with a tissue paper, will I make Wadu?